# Bowers & Wilkins P5 wireless headphones on OSX causing problems for other bluetooth devices

Tags: audio, bluetooth, mouse, headphones

I've been using a Microsoft bluetooth mouse with my MacBook Pro (Early 2015 El Capitan 10.11.5) without issue for several months. OSX Bluetooth Firmware Version: v119 c4633.

However, since pairing the Bowers & Wilkins P5 Wireless headphones via bluetooth the mouse has started to automatically disconnect. Both devices work simultaneously for a short period (~5 min) until the mouse drops connection. The mouse is then shown to be disconnected in the bluetooth system settings.

The headphones do not drop connection nor lose audio. Once the headphones are manually disconnected the mouse connection is restored.

How can I use both devices simultaneously?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a few months back but it resolved itself when I upgraded to Sierra. Unless there's a reason for holding fire with the upgrade, I'd suggest giving that a go to see if this resolves the problem.

Do you have other Bluetooth headphones/devices, or perhaps another laptop to test with? Would be interested to see if a combination of other devices had the same affect on your Microsoft mouse. Although the disconnection only occurs when the P5 Wireless are connected, it sounds to me as though this could be a red herring!

Comment: Will give it a try and report back once done